# How ubuntu parameter by uuidgen and remove "-" format

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, azure-cli, azure-cli2

What trouble I have :
[image]

What I'd like to:
input :

```
az acr create --resource-group demo --name somefuntion(uuidgen) --sku Basic
```

expectd :

```
az acr create --resource-group demo --name "daf506ea86a64c478f5762238a3cc208" --sku Basic
```

What I've tried :
I know `uuidgen` can get uuid like

```
$ uuidgen
daf506ea-86a6-4c47-8f57-62238a3cc208
```

Comment: not `az acr create --resource-group demo --name $(uuidgen) --sku Basic` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$()` allows for [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) in Bash, i.e., it allows the output of a command to be substituted in place of the command itself.

[`tr` command](https://linuxhint.com/bash_tr_command/) in Unix can be used to transform the generated UUID to the required format.

Putting these together, you get:

```
az acr create --resource-group demo--name $(uuidgen | tr -d '-') --sku Basic
```

which should help you with what you want.